# Monodevelop on Mac how to I set the working directory for debugging

Tags: macos, debugging, monodevelop, working-directory

I know I can set custom run commands for running which includes setting the working directory but I cannot seem to find the setting to set the working directory when debugging. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that this is Mac/OSX specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger uses the same working directory that "Run" uses.

Answer (score 5):

To set a working directory in "Run" or "Debug" mode :

- in "Project Options", add a "Run/Custom Command" with type "**Execute**"
- set the command: **${TargetFile}**
- set your working directory