# In monodevelop, how to set the working directory when running your code

Tags: monodevelop

does anyone know if it is possible to set the working directory for running the application you create in monodevelop?

The app is written to the bin/Debug directory and that seems to be the working directory when you debug the application.  For my application (which I am porting from Windows) it takes an XML configuration file which references other XML files, the paths (in the configuration xml) I use are relative paths (which is sensible imo).

IIRC Visual Studio lets you set the working directory when you are debugging, does monodevelop?  I had a good look around the options and tried to search for an answer, but no luck.

thanks
Dave

Comment: Thanks DMK that seemed to solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware "Run" and "Debug" mode use the same working directory.

Have a look at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186009/monodevelop-on-mac-how-to-i-set-the-working-directory-for-debugging/11051803#11051803)